# switch to Iframe Error: invalid argument: 'id' can not be string

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Encountered unexpected behavior of Webdriver: when I trying to pass a constant to frame() in the driver.switchTo () command.frame() it returns an error that id can't be a string. Although the selenium documentation just passes the string and it should work

```
let newAd = await driver.findElement(By.css('*[data-google-query-id]'))   
let getIframe = await newAd.findElement(By.css('iframe'))
let iframeName = await getIframe.getAttribute('name')
  console.log(await iframeName);
let currentIframe = await driver.switchTo().frame(iframeName)
  console.log(await currentIframe)
```

[Error from Selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gND4x.png)

Any idea why?

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure: which one of these lines is line 58?

Comment: It seems to want a try-catch to surround the async.

Comment: @ChrisG line 58 is catch(err) {
        throw new Error(err.message);
    }

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced that issue, and I found out that I was importing an empty string just like this `import '';` , instead of a module in my typescript project. Hope this may help you.